# Deploying my Japplet in Netbeans

Tags: netbeans

I'm banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out.

I'm using NetBeans 6.9.1 and I have a project of type "Java Application." This project contains no Main method, but instead a Japplet named AlarmClock.java. When I right-click and run AlarmClock.java, it runs correctly with no problems. What I can't figure out is how to get this applet to run on a website (or even locally on my computer for that matter). I've tried building it and opening up *ProjectDirectory*/dist/launch.html which starts up launch.JNLP which opens up a webpage with a space for my applet, but this space just contains an error message.

I'm not sure if it's something wrong with my project settings, and I don't know what a "codebase" is or whether "Web Start" should be on. Do I need a main method that opens up my applet, and how would I do that? Some advice would be hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That is a typical situation where a full IDE is too much. To understand the background is better to take a simple text editor and let you guide by a [Java Applet Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/getStarted.html).

Once you feel good with applets make the same exercise with your preferred IDE. If not you have to learn Applets + "How my IDE handles Applets" at the same time.